# The server response was: 5.7.0 Authentication Required. Learn more at

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq

I tried to run this code and it shows this error.This is reset password where user is required to insert the email address. When the email address is valid, the admin will send the link to the user to do resetting password.  [image]

```
    protected void btnResetPwd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string emailAddress = txtEmail.Text;

        User u = db.Users.Single(x => x.EmailAddress == emailAddress);


        if (u != null)
        {
            lblMessage.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.LimeGreen;
            MailMessage mailMessage = new MailMessage();

            StringBuilder sbEmailBody = new StringBuilder();
            sbEmailBody.Append("Dear " + u.Name + ",<br/><br/>");
            sbEmailBody.Append("Please click on the following link to reset your password");
            sbEmailBody.Append("<br/>"); sbEmailBody.Append("http://localhost/Assignment/Registration/ChangePwd.aspx?uid=" +u.Id);
            sbEmailBody.Append("<br/><br/>");
            sbEmailBody.Append("<b>Pragim Technologies</b>");

            mailMessage.IsBodyHtml = true;

            mailMessage.Body = sbEmailBody.ToString();
            mailMessage.Subject = "Reset Your Password";
            SmtpClient smtpClient = new SmtpClient("smtp.gmail.com", 587);

            smtpClient.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential()
            {
                UserName = "YourEmail@gmail.com",
                Password = "YourPassword"
            };
            string to = u.EmailAddress;
            string from = "potato@gmail.com";

            smtpClient.EnableSsl = true;

            mailMessage.From = new MailAddress(from);
            mailMessage.To.Add(to);
            smtpClient.Send(mailMessage);
            smtpClient.UseDefaultCredentials = false;

            lblMessage.Text = "An email with instructions to reset your password is sent to your registered email";


        }
        else
        {
            lblMessage.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
            lblMessage.Text = "Email Address not found!";
        }

    }
```

And this is my web.config

```
        <system.net>
        <mailSettings>
        <smtp from="Admin &lt;potato@gmail.com&gt;">
        <network host="smt.gmail.com"
                 port="587"
             enableSsl="true"
             userName="potato@gmail.com"
             password="password"/>
              </smtp>
             </mailSettings>
             </system.net>
```

Answer (score 15):

It would appear that nothing is wrong with your code, but that gmail is not set up correctly.

Enable 2 factor authentication, then **USE AN APP PASSWORD** - see https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/185833?hl=en.  **For app passwords to work, Two-factor authentication must be enabled first.*

If cannot find option for getting App Password under **How you sign in to Google**,  use the search box above named Search Google Account and search App Password.

[This YouTube video can help with the whole process.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lk5dhDzfzsU)

Of course you can use your own code, just watch the process of enabling 2 factor authentication and getting App Password.

Comment: Thanks! This is exactly what I was missing!

Answer (score 1):

Also it could be related with weakness of your password. Don't mind if there is writing STRONG while picking a password. Pick a password as complicated as possible if it contains numbers like 123 it could cause problem.

> Because this potentially makes your account less secure, you'll need to update your password to include a minimum of 8 characters, a mixture of letters and numbers, and at least one special character (e.g., @, !, #, etc.).  Your SMTP settings may not work if your password doesn't meet these requirements.

[https://support.mindbodyonline.com/s/article/204253056-SMTP-errors-What-does-it-mean?language=en_US#:~:text=The%20SMTP%20server%20requires%20a,Yes%22%20in%20your%20SMTP%20settings](https://support.mindbodyonline.com/s/article/204253056-SMTP-errors-What-does-it-mean?language=en_US#:%7E:text=The%20SMTP%20server%20requires%20a,Yes%22%20in%20your%20SMTP%20settings).

Answer (score 1):

it's so easy,
authenticator is playing an important role in smtp
go to your google account, go to security and set 2 step verification.
then you will see app password, go to app password select custom choose a name, and copy the code gives you.
in your code put that code in to the password
UserName = "YourEmail@gmail.com",
Password = "AppPassword"

everything goes well then
good luck